# Problems with UDP Received and Sent UDP Packages?

Tags: java, sockets, udp, datagram

I am trying to write a simple program about UDP Connections to learn about them. I have implemented some basic things but when I try to send and get back what I sent but I face some problems like,

When I do this ;
send a string

"asd" to server I get back asdxxxxxxxxxx
and when I try to print What I get in the server I get [B@5f186fab

How can I solve this problem ?

To be more clear I am sending you a few lines of code ,

In client;

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String result = in.nextLine();
        // send request
    byte[] buf = new byte[1000];
    String read = result;
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(result.getBytes(),  result.getBytes().length, address, 4445);
    socket.send(packet);

        // get response
    packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
    socket.receive(packet);

    // display response
    String received = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
    System.out.println("Quote of the Moment: " + received);
```

In server ;

```
            byte[] buf = new byte[1000];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
            socket.receive(packet);
            byte[] received = packet.getData();
            System.out.println(received.toString());

                // figure out response

        // send the response to the client at "address" and "port"
            InetAddress address = packet.getAddress();
            int port = packet.getPort();
            packet = new DatagramPacket(received, received.length, address, port);
            socket.send(packet);
```

Thank you all

**EDIT 1**  I think I have problems with my buffer but I dont know how to solve .

Comment: Are you actually, literally getting `asdxxxxxxxxxx` (or `asdxxxxxxx`)? Or is that just a placeholder in your post (and comment below)?

Comment: Actually it is not and x, it s a square like [] and I am really getting it from console.

Comment: Look into printing what you receive (on both the server and client sides) both as a plain string as well as in hexadecimal. See if that gives any clues as to where it might be coming from. The squares probably represent nonprintable characters.

Comment: I think the problem is the buffer I create in server side which is byte[256] but I do not know how to create it dynamically according to coming packet ?

Comment: Set it to the maximum expected packet size + 1. Then if you ever get a packet whose size is that big you know there is data trunction, or an error somewhere, or your expectations are wrong. The maximum practical size for a UDP packet is under 1500 bytes in any case so 2k wouldn't hurt you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(received));
```

but what you probably want is

```
System.out.println(new String(received, o, lengthRead, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked on server side, but actually I dont understand  why I stil get asdxxxxxxx when I send asd .

Comment: @Ozer Print out the `received.length`  and see how big the buffer is, after you received the data

Comment: @nos Actually I tried it but both strings and buffers length are the same and 256

Comment: @Ozer, I have changed the second example to take the length if its not the whole buffer. If you are going to read one javadoc this year, I suggest you read the one for String. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you fixed this?

Otherwise, what I've found is that if you declare a receiving `byte[] buf` with a capacity that's greater than the length string you're actually receiving, you'll end up with the rest of the buffer full of unwanted bytes.

Eg. if you declare `byte[] received = new byte[1000];` but only receive a string of 4 bytes, you'll end up with 996 unwanted bytes.

One quick way around this is to do something like

```
byte[] received = packet.getData();
System.out.println(received.toString().trim());
```

`trim()` did the trick for me. Hope that helps you!

Comment: `received.toString()` will return something of the form `[Bxxxxxxx`, not the contents of the byte array, and trimming that is futile.